# SQL stored procedure doesn't stop executing

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that executes indefinitely. I can't see where I have created an infinite loop or anything. Any suggestions as to why this keeps executing?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_RemovePaddingPicture_Name
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @test nvarchar(50)

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Picture_Name
        FROM PEOPLEGENERAL

    OPEN cur
    FETCH FROM cur

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PEOPLEGENERAL
        SET PICTURE_NAME = RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME)
        WHERE CURRENT of cur

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur
END
```

I created this stored procedure to update a column. It keeps executing.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I am curious why you think a cursor is the best way to accomplish your task here?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with the value returned from the cursor for one thing.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE proc_RemovePaddingPicture_Name -- used a different prefix
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @picName nvarchar(50) -- meanfull name for variable

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Picture_Name
        FROM PEOPLEGENERAL
        WHERE PICTURE_NAME != RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME) -- added to only update records with a difference

    
    OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @picName -- assign returned value to variable
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PEOPLEGENERAL
        SET PICTURE_NAME = RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME)
        WHERE @picName = Picture_Name -- use of assigned variable
    
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @picName -- assign returned value to variable
    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur
END
```

That all said you could also just do this with one statement provided the table is not that large that it would cause an issue.

```
UPDATE PEOPLEGENERAL SET PICTURE_NAME = RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME)
```

or if there are only a limited number of records that should be touched because the value is the same.

```
UPDATE PEOPLEGENERAL 
SET PICTURE_NAME = RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME) 
WHERE PICTURE_NAME != RTRIM(PICTURE_NAME)
```